# Helmholtz decomposition proof

Tags: calculus, curl

Reading [derivation of Helmholtz decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition#Derivation) in wikipedia, there are two points I do not understand. First one appears in the step:

$$
\begin{align}
\dots
&=-\frac{1}{4\pi}\left[\nabla\left(\nabla\cdot\int_V\frac{\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}')}{\left|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'\right|}\mathrm{d}V'\right)-\nabla\times\left(\nabla\times\int_V\frac{\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}')}{\left|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'\right|}\mathrm{d}V'\right)\right] \\
&= -\frac{1}{4\pi} \left[\nabla\left(\int_V\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}')\cdot\nabla\frac{1}{\left|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'\right|}\mathrm{d}V'\right)+\nabla\times\left(\int_V\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}')\times\nabla\frac{1}{\left|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'\right|}\mathrm{d}V'\right)\right] \\
&= \dots
\end{align}
$$

where sign of second term jumps from "-" to "+" at same time than curl is inserted in the integral, something I do not see why must change the sign.

The second doubts appears a few lines after, where I can read:

$$
\mathbf{a}\times\nabla\psi =\psi(\nabla\times\mathbf{a})-\nabla \times (\psi\mathbf{a})
$$

because, starting from product rule of curl over scalar and vector:

$$
\nabla \times (\psi\mathbf{a}) = \psi(\nabla\times\mathbf{a}) + \mathbf{a}\times\nabla\psi 
$$

I expected:

$$
\mathbf{a}\times\nabla\psi = -\psi(\nabla\times\mathbf{a})+\nabla \times (\psi\mathbf{a})
$$

Could be two obvious errors from my side, but I can not find them. Any help is welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases: the sign *CHANGES* if you reverse order of cross product.

$${\bf a}\times {\bf b}=-{\bf b}\times{\bf a}$$

There is a reverse of order in cross product from $\nabla\times {\bf F}f({\bf r})$ to $ {\bf F}\times \nabla f({\bf r})$. Note that the derivative works on $\bf r$, not $\bf r'$ so ${\bf F}$ acts as a constant. So, the minus sign is *correct*, because the reverse of order happened.

In the second one, you are again reversing the order without paying attention. The product you wrote is wrong, it should be:

$$\nabla\times (\psi {\bf a})=\psi(\nabla\times {\bf a})+(\nabla\psi)\times{\bf a}$$

Notice how ${\bf a}$ which gives the vector direction to the right operand of $\times$, stays on the right, and $\nabla$ which acts as a vector on the left, stays on the left.